# WinSCP like sync on Android

Tags: sync

An android client needs to sync files from the server and then execute app.

If it is a windows client, I can use autohotkey and winscp to do this.

`appA.ahk`

```
SplitPath, A_ScriptFullPath, name, dir, ext, name_no_ext, drive
FileDelete, %dir%/%name_no_ext%.log
runwait,D:\Tools\WinSCPPortable\WinSCP.exe /script="%dir%/%name_no_ext%.txt" /log="%dir%/%name_no_ext%.log"
sleep 3000
run,C:\Program Files (x86)\APP\APP.exe
```

`appA.txt`

```
option batch abort
option confirm off
option transfer binary
open ftp://User:123456789@192.168.1.11

synchronize local -filemask=|*.db "C:\Program Files (x86)\APP\data" APP/data
close
exit
```

How can I do similar task in android?